# About a Qiskit Function

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit

I want to understand this Qiskit function (a function for creating the gate CNX with Python): more specifically i don't understand what's the rotations (Y and Z) over the qubits for ?
I added inline questions in the code below :

```
def cnx(qc, *qubits):
 if len(qubits) >= 3:
  last = qubits[-1]
  #What's the goal of the next two lines ?
  qc.crz(np.pi/2, qubits[-2], qubits[-1])
  qc.cry(np.pi/2, 0, 0, qubits[-2],qubits[-1])

  #Is this a recursive call to cnx ?
  cnx(qc,*qubits[:-2],qubits[-1])

  #what's this flip yielding ?
  qc.cry(-np.pi/2, 0, 0, qubits[-2], qubits[-1])

  #what about this line ?
  cnx(qc,*qubits[:-2],qubits[-1])

  #what about this line too?
  qc.crz(-np.pi/2,qubits[-2],qubits[-1])
```

Thanks !

Comment: Hi! Could you tell us where you found this function? I searched for ["cnx" in qiskit-terra](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/search?q=cnx&unscoped_q=cnx), without any result. I also searched ["cnx" in qiskit-aqua](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/search?q=cnx&type=Commits) and the only results are commits showing that the `cnx` function has been removed the 9th of May.

Comment: Sory i don't recall from where i found it

Comment: I think this is the method from [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/4e743e265bdf78ef28bd7e179fe7bde8cf67a385/community/games/game_engines/composite_gates.py#L57) which is based on Lemma 7.9 in the paper [here](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.52.3457).